# Run bash command whenever ViM is being started

Tags: vim, ctags

So I would like to run the following command whenever ViM starts:

```
ctags -R .
```

Is this possible?
Preferably I would like to have something in my `~/.vimrc` that does this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:help :!cmd`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21cmd) in your .vimrc:

```
!ctags -R .
```

To avoid the hit-enter prompt (but still see the ctags output), prepend `:silent`:

```
silent !ctags -R .
```

To completely silence the output (but then you won't notice problems until you implement another notification), use [`system()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) instead:

```
call system('ctags -R .')
```

To avoid that the run time of ctags delays using Vim, you can start the task asynchronously (on Unix):

```
call system('ctags -R . &')
```

Comment: Moreover, you can put this command in `.vimrc` under your project directory and don't run it elsewhere. As I know it not very secure but it's very convenient. Also, you need to add `set exrc` in your main `.vimrc`

Comment: does `!ctags -R .` just get placed as a line in the .vimrc and then it will automatically run on startup? Or does it require anything like autocmds?

Comment: @StunBrick Yes, it will run automatically, but very early during startup (cp. `:help initialization`), so no files have been loaded yet, and so on. Luckily, this doesn't matter for tags generation. You could use `:autocmd VimEnter * !ctags ...` to defer the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this to .vimrc:

```
" === generate ctags
call system('ctags -R . ')
```